# iOS load a tableview depending on GPS position

Tags: ios, geolocation, location

I have some records in a DB that, between other data, contains a city name.
I want to load in a tableview only the data where the city matches the user's city.
I have already used the reverse Geocoding to get the user's city:

```
[self.geoCoder reverseGeocodeLocation: location completionHandler:
 ^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {

     CLPlacemark *placemark = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];
     country = [placemark.addressDictionary valueForKey:@"Country"];
     city = [placemark.addressDictionary valueForKey:@"City"];
     NSString *title = [NSString stringWithFormat:NSLocalizedString(@"You're in %@", nil),city];

     NSLog(@"%@", title);
     [locationController.locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
 }];
```

The problem is that the city name is localized. For example: I live in Zaragoza, Spain and I've set a DB record containing the city "Zaragoza".
But my phone language is Italian and as a city name I get "Saragozza" that does not matches the field in the DB record.
Any idea on how to do this?

EDIT: Since I'm using Parse as a backend for this app, I've just found the method whereKey:nearGeoPoint:withinMiles in their API that will solve my problem. I've changed the DB record to be a "geopoint" instead of a city name and I'll load all the records within X miles from the user location.
Anyways, I will keep this question open because I'd like to know how to do it without using Parse's API.

Comment: Don't compare city names directly. Instead define geographical regions using a circle or polygon. CLRegion can be useful here.

Comment: I should define regions for each city in the world then, I don't think I can do it.